# Error Cors Nestjs Vercel from origin 'http://localhost:3000'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cors, nestjs, vercel

"How are you? Here, I'm looking to nourish myself a bit from your understanding. I deployed a Nestjs app on Vercel, but when I try to access the URL generated by Vercel, I have the following problem: Access to fetch at 'http://example.vercel.app/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request."

"I deployed my Nestjs app on Vercel and I got the following error:

```
[error of CORS in Frontend Reacjs & Typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pvZF.png)
```

My vercel.json file looks like this:

```
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/main.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "src/main.ts",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The main.ts file looks like this:

```
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);

  SwaggerModule.setup(`docs`, app, document);

  app.enableCors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    allowedHeaders: 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
  });

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
    }),
  );

  await app.listen(3001);
```

And the Login.service file where the call is made looks like this:

```
const response = await fetch(`http://${BASE_URL}/auth/login`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST'
      },
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
    });
```